# Create class from dynamically created list of bases

Tags: python

Is there any way to create a class from a dynamic list of base classes?

```
def dynamic_class_creator(base, base2):
    class Derived(base, base2):
        pass
    return Derived

class Mixin1(object):
    def greet(self):
        print ("Howdy!")

class Mixin1a(object):
    def insult(self):
        print ("You have a lot to learn.")

class Mixin2(object):
    def insult(self):
        print ("Idiot!")

polite = dynamic_class_creator(Mixin1, Mixin1a)()
polite.greet()
polite.insult()

complex = dynamic_class_creator(Mixin1, Mixin2)()
complex.greet()
complex.insult()
```

This works as expected:

```
Howdy!                    
You have a lot to learn.  
Howdy!                    
Idiot!
```

But I can't figure out how to assign these bases from a list of arbitrary length:

```
def dynamic_class_creator(*bases):
    class Derived(*bases):
        pass
    return Derived
(...)
```

gives:

```
  File "../test2.py", line 4
    class Derived(*bases):  
                  ^         
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT**

One suggested solution:

```
def dynamic_class_creator(*bases):
    class Derived(bases):
        pass
    return Derived
(...)
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    polite = dynamic_class_creator(Mixin1, Mixin1a)()
  File "../test2.py", line 4, in dynamic_class_creator
    class Derived(bases):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    tuple() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the three-argument form of the `type()` constructor. Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), "*With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the `class` statement.*"

```
# TESTED with Python3
def dynamic_class_creator(*bases):
    return type('Derived', bases, {})
```

The problem with the above is that you lose the `class` syntax. This makes it difficult, for example, to add methods to `Derived`.

You can keep the nice syntax of class declaration, and *still* modify the call to `type()` by using a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

Here is a complete example, demonstrating the use of `metaclass=`, `type()`, and both regular and mix-in base classes.

```
# TESTED with Python3
def dynamic_class_creator(*mixins):
    def metaclass(name, bases, members):
        return type(name, bases + mixins, members)

    class Derived(BaseClass, metaclass=metaclass):
        def praise(self):
            print("Good job!")

    return Derived

class BaseClass(object):
    def goodbye(self):
        print("Goodbye!")

class Mixin1(object):
    def greet(self):
        print("Howdy!")

class Mixin1a(object):
    def insult(self):
        print("You have a lot to learn.")

class Mixin2(object):
    def insult(self):
        print("Idiot!")

polite = dynamic_class_creator(Mixin1, Mixin1a)()
polite.greet()
polite.insult()
polite.praise()
polite.goodbye()

complex = dynamic_class_creator(Mixin1, Mixin2)()
complex.greet()
complex.insult()
```

You can pass arbitrary keywords to the metaclass function. Consider this example:

```
# TESTED with Python3
def mixin_metaclass(name, bases, members, mixins):
    return type(name, bases+mixins, members)

def dynamic_class_creator(*mixins):
    class Derived(metaclass=mixin_metaclass, mixins=mixins):
        pass
    return Derived
```

Finally, note that all of the above examples are tested with Python3. Here is a Python2 version:

```
# TESTED with Python2
def dynamic_class_creator(*mixins):
    def metaclass(name, bases, members):
        return type(name, mixins+bases, members)
    class Derived(object):
        __metaclass__ = metaclass
        def praise(self):
            print("Good job!")
    return Derived
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is that I am coding for python 2 (internal limitation). So I have to do `__metaclass__ = metaclass`. Also, if I want to make sure `Derived` is a subclass of `object`, it needs to be `... tuple(mixins) + bases...`, otherwise then MRO fails. But this totally works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added a Python2 example.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution based on Robᵩ's if you are already using another metaclass (as I am):

**Python 3**

```
def mixin_metaclass(name, bases, members, mixins, super_meta=type):
    return super_meta(name, bases + mixins, members)

def dynamic_class_creator(*mixins):
    class Derived(metaclass=mixin_metaclass, mixins=mixins, super_meta=MyMeta):
        pass
    return Derived
```

**Python 2**

```
def mixin_meta(super_meta, *mixins):
    def _meta(name, bases, members):
        return super_meta(name, mixins + bases, members)
    return _meta

def dynamic_class_creator(*mixins):
    class Derived(object):
        __metaclass__ = mixin_meta(MyMeta, *mixins)
    return Derived
```